# Basic Algebras: Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

A $k$-algebra $A$ is called *basic* if for every set of primitive orthogonal idempotents $\left\{e_1, \dots , e_n\right\}$ such that $1=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i$ we have that $$e_iA\cong e_jA\Leftrightarrow i=j.$$

If $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra such that we have a decomposition $1=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i$ with $e_iA\cong e_jA\Leftrightarrow i=j$, then by the Krull-Schmidt theorem we have that if $1=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i'$ is another such decomposition, then $e_i'A\cong e_j'A\Leftrightarrow i=j$. Hence for finite-dimensional algebras the definition of a basic algebra can be formulated in terms of one decomposition of $1$ into primitive orthogonal idempotents.

> But is there an example of an (infinite dimensional) algebra with two such decompositions such that one looks basic and the other doesn't?

Comment: What does $\cong$ mean in this context?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  Excellent question, I assume they are isomorphic as modules (otherwise invoking the Krull-Schmidt theorem is meaningless). However, I read the definition in a book that doesn't explicitly state whether they are isomorphic as modules or algebras.

Comment: Isomorphic as modules. The point is that these are the indecomposable projectives, and being basic prevents "additional" automorphisms of the algebra coming (as a module over itself) from mixing these. No idea what happens for infinite dimensional ones.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Indeed, the definition as given in 'Representation theory of Artin algebras' is even formulated in terms of the indecomposable projectives. This definition is taken from the book 'Quiver representations' by Ralf Schiffler. I'm wondering what the role of 'for every'-statement in this definition is. In the context of the book (namely finite-dimensional algebras) it is unimportant.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, all unital commutative $C^*$-algebras fail. Polynomial algebras and free algebras don't work either. I know this question is not so important, but it would be interesting to see an example of such an algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=M_2(k)$ be the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices, with $1_B=e_B+f_B$ a decomposition into primitive orthogonal idempotents, so $e_B$ and $f_B$ are conjugate.

Let $C=k\times k$, with $1_C=e_C+f_C$ a decomposition into primitive orthogonal idempotents, so $e_C$ and $f_C$ are not conjugate.

Let $A$ be the coproduct of $A$ and $B$ in the category of $k$-algebras (i.e., the $k$-algebra generated by $B$ and $C$ subject to no relations other than those that already hold in $B$ and $C$). Concretely, if you choose bases $\{1_B,b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ and $\{1_C,c\}$ of $B$ and $C$, then $A$ has basis the set of words in $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,c\}$ with alternating $b$s and $c$s.

Then $A=e_BA\oplus f_BA$ where $e_BA\cong f_BA$, and $A=e_CA\oplus f_CA$ where $e_CA\not\cong f_CA$.

The idempotents all remain primitive in $A$, since if, for example, $e_B$ decomposes as $e_B=e+f$, then $e_B$ commutes with $e$ and $f$, but it's easy to check that an element of $B$ can only commute in $A$ with other elements of $B$, so this decomposition would already happen in $B$.

Comment: How do you know that $e_CA\not\cong f_CA$? I know that if $e,f$ are conjugate, then $eA\cong fA$ and the converse holds if $A$ is finite dimensional. But why is the converse true in this example?

Comment: @Mathematician42 By the universal property of the coproduct, there's a ring homomorphism $A\to A'=B\otimes_k C$ induced by the natural maps $B\to A'$ and $C\to A'$. If $e_CA\cong f_CA$ then $e_CA'\cong e_CA\otimes_AA'\cong f_CA\otimes_AA'\cong f_CA'$, and now you're in a finite-dimensional case (the restriction of $e_CA'$ to $C$ is just the direct sum of four copies of $e_CC$).

Comment: @Mathematician42 Actually, in general $e,f$ being conjugate is equivalent to $eA\cong fA$ *and* $(1-e)A\cong (1-f)A$, which we do have here since $1-e_C=f_C$.

Comment: Very good answer, nice to see how you turned two finite dimensional algebras with different properties into a infinite dimensional one sharing both properties. I find it somewhat surprising that the example is not so difficult, but then again, the notion of basic algebras is used in the finite dimensional setting anyway.